# Animate LazyColumn item compose

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

Is there any way to this day to animate the visbility of an item from LazyColumn/LazyRow?
I can't seem to find an option for this, **I tried to do a extra parameter of boolean type for my data class object** and then use it there like:

`AnimatedVisbility(visible = item.visibility){}`

But sadly that's not working even if duration for `fadeIn()` is **8000L**

I've read that this is on the way but might be wrong, anyways is there a way to animate an item list?

Answer (score 1):

Workarounds:-

1.) Add modifier.animateContentSize to your items, then animate the height and width of those items to zero.dp

2.) Pass in a list item (a variable) to the `items` block of `LazyColumn` and then modify this list variable to trigger a recompostion. I guess Compose will ensure that only the necessary bits get recomposed.